# Getting research jobs in Canada for immigrants

Tags: career-path, job-search, job, canada

I have a PhD in engineering from an African university which is obviously *not well known* and now I work at the same university as an assistant professor.

I think about immigrating to Canada (EE system), is there any ***actual*** chance that I can get a research position in Canada? Not necessarily at universities. How can I improve my chances? what are the criteria? should I forget about getting such jobs? Hit me with reality!

Comment: I do not think the question in this form can be answered without knowing your particular situation, academic profile, and what kind of jobs you consider. Non-academic employment is also not exactly a topic of Academia.SE.

Comment: Can you teach computer science?  It seems there is less of a surplus of computer science faculty compared to other areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that it is unlikely that you will. The reason is that even for graduates/PhD's of well known institutes like the University of Toronto, it is very hard to get an academic position in Canada. Therefore, if you come from a not well known institute, and you have not published in the top places in your field, and you have no strong connections to the relevant international academic community, then it is hard to get an academic position.

Possibly, there are some academic teaching positions available. I do not know, but they are not research, and I would assume that even for them it will be very hard.

The criteria for improving your chances are listed in the first paragraph.

Comment: "there are some academic teaching positions available."  Those also require a PhD from a well known university, a publication record, and a teaching record.

Comment: Actually, I doubt that the general visibility of the doctoral institution has much relevance and certainly being from Africa does not. But the publication record, etc. is important. For any position, for any candidate, you need to show that you are a good (great) prospect with a high likelihood of success. Diamonds are found in coal mines, by the way. For the OP, who is already an assistant professor the publications and letters of recommendation would be paramount. Other things for a teaching position.

Comment: Affirmative Action policies might improve his odds of finding something. The ethics of these policies can be ... controversial, however, depending on your politics.